# Python: Button to reset a label to zero

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I am trying to do a count of a price sum, but I am having trouble getting my reset function to make the total price go back to $0. The actual variable that holds the value resets to zero. I just need to reset the label. tkinter is being used.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("QTouch 10")
global total, count
total = 0
count = StringVar()
```

--List of things I used not involved--

```
amount = Label(root, textvariable=count)
count.set("$--") 

def res():
    total = 0
    **count.set("$--")**
    for n in names:
        names[names.index(n)][3] = 0
    label = Label(root, text="0").grid(row=names.index(n)+1, column=4)  


amount.grid(row=10, column=4)

reset = Button(root, text="Reset", command=lambda *args: res()).grid(row=10, 
column=1)
```

Comment: I think you want to create your Label once and then make the button update it - instead of making the Button create a new Label each time it's clicked.

Comment: Does `names` change across invocations of `res`? If names is constant I would not create the `Label` inside res, create that label once then just update the existing label.

Comment: This is what I am trying to change. Instead of making a new label on top of the old one I want to edit the one and only label. But I am having issues with an object error and cant seem to edit the label.

Answer (score 1):

This is my rework to make a minimal example from your code.  I removed all the logic having to do with `names` as it wasn't part of the stated problem and wasn't complete (`names` wasn't defined.)  I've set the initial value of `total` and `count` to $10 and let `res()` reset it to 0:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

total = 10
count = StringVar()
amount = Label(root, textvariable=count)
count.set("$10")

def res():
    global total
    total = 0
    count.set("$0")

amount.grid(row=10, column=4)

Button(root, text="Reset", command=res).grid(row=10, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

This appears to work as intended.

Things to note: your explanation said `"$0"` but your code says `"$--"`; you don't seem to have a handle on what the `global` keyword does; you added a layer of indirection via a `lambda` that may not need to be there.

Comment: Could you explain what the lambda does in the command for the button?

Comment: @Paral, the `command` parameter points to a function.  In this case, I pointed it at the `res` function.  Sometimes there's a mismatch between the parameters that `command` wants to pass and what the function expects.  This is a situation where a `lambda` can be used to overcome that mismatch by appearing to accept one parameter list but calling the function with another.  There are likely other reasons, for using a `lambda` in this situation.